# Solve $z=px+qy+p^2+q^2$ by Charpit's Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

ind the complete integral of partial differential equation  $z=px+qy+p^2+q^2$.
**My attempt:**
Let $F=px+qy+p^2+q^2=0$. Then by 
Charpit's auxiliary equations
$\dfrac{dp}{F_x+pF_z}=\dfrac{dq}{F_y+qF_z}=\dfrac{dz}{-pF_p-qF_q}=\dfrac{dx}{-F_p}=\dfrac{dy}{-F_q}$
we have
$\dfrac{dp}{0}=\dfrac{dq}{0}=\dfrac{dz}{-p(x+2p)-q(y+2q)}=\dfrac{dx}{-(x+2p)}=\dfrac{dy}{-(y+2q)}$ .
This implies $p=a$=constant. Putting this in given equation, $q=\dfrac{-y\pm \sqrt{y^2-4(a^2+ax-z)}}{2}$. What can I do after this to solve the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given equation is 
\begin{equation}
F=z-px-qy-p^2-q^2=0.
\end{equation}
Charpit's auxiliary equations are 
\begin{align*}
& \dfrac{dp}{F_x+pF_z}=\dfrac{dq}{F_y+qF_z}=\dfrac{dz}{-pF_p-qF_q}=\dfrac{dx}{-F_p}=\dfrac{dy}{-F_q}\\
\implies & \dfrac{dp}{-p+p(1)}=\dfrac{dq}{-q+q(1)}=\dfrac{dz}{-p(-x-2p)-q(-y-2q)}=\dfrac{dx}{-x-2p}=\dfrac{dy}{-y-2q}\\
\implies & \dfrac{dp}{0}=\dfrac{dq}{0}=\dfrac{dz}{px+qy+2p^2+2q^2}=\dfrac{dx}{-x-2p}=\dfrac{dy}{-y-2q}
\end{align*}
First fraction implies, $dp=0\implies p=a$.
Similarly, let $q=b.$
Now, $dz=pdx+qdy\implies dz=adx+bdy\implies z=ax+by+c$.
Putting the value of $z$ in the given equation,
$ax+by+c=ax+by+a^2+b^2\implies c=a^2+b^2$
Therefore, $z=ax+by+a^2+b^2$.
This is the complete solution.